# Find file in program files and launch that file

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to write a program that downloads Team Viewer and installs it and if its already installed, launch teamviewer from programfiles instead of re-downloading it.

I have it so it downloads and installs teamviewer into the correct folder but i cant figure out how to tell my program to search in either Program Files (x86) for 64bit or program files for 32 bit search the directory and sub directories for teamviewer.exe and launch the program. Here is the code i have so far.

Thanks.

I solved it using this code. It searches for Teamviewer in the correct program files folder and launches the program . This does not check if you have it installed or not, i have a check earlier in my program that detects it but it would be easy to add.

```
private void teamviewerbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //start button

        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE").Contains("64"))
        {
            string path = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Teamviewer\"; //specify starting folder location for searching
            string searchPattern = "teamviewer.exe*"; //what do you want to search for?

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            FileInfo[] files =
                di.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string tvE = (file.FullName.ToString()); //takes found file and references full file path
                Process.Start(tvE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string path = @"c:\Program Files\Teamviewer\"; //specify starting folder location for searching
            string searchPattern = "teamviewer.exe*"; //what do you want to search for?

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            FileInfo[] files =
                di.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string tvE = (file.FullName.ToString()); //takes found file and references full file path
                Process.Start(tvE);
            }
        }   

        //end button
    }
```

Comment: So, all you need is to find the path of program files folder on any 32/64 bits windows?

Comment: might want to be a little more descriptive on your variable names. (button6 means literally nothing)

Comment: ex.Message.ToString() can just be ex.Message

Comment: button 6 in just the button im pressing to download teamviewer. @ Jonas im trying to locate teamviewer.exe whether its in programfiles x86 or regular program files depending on the operating system, and return the file path such as: C:\program files (x86)\teamviewer\version7\teamviewer.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (files.Length == 1)
{
    Process.Start(files[0]);
}
```

Comment: What i'm really looking for is a way to search C:\program files\teamviewer and locate the file Teamviewer.exe and return its path ie: c:\program files\teamviewer\version7\teamviewer.exe then i can use the code like this 

           string tvE = @"PATH FOUND FROM PROGRAMFILES";                    
                    Process.Start(tvE);

Comment: the problem arises from the fact that you just scan the main one. TeamViewer is 32-bit, so just change Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles to Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles32

Comment: on 32-bit Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles is always "Program Files", whereas Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles32 is "Program Files" on 32-bit and "Program Files (x86)" on 64-bit

Comment: if it happens to add itself to the path during install, you could leverage that :)

Comment: then couldn't you just use 'Process.Start("teamviewer.exe")'?

Comment: I tried 'Process.Start("teamviewer.exe"); but it says it can't find the file specified. I'm trying create a method to search in C:\program files\teamviewer\ that locates TeamViewer.exe and returns the Teamviewer.exe path where it is installed. 

ultimately, i'd like to hit a button, team viewer setup downloads to a file, teamviewer installs using a batch file, if teamviewer is closed and you hit the button again, I'd like teamviewer to launch instead of re-download. I'm just stuck at the point where the method returns the installation path on the hd of teamviewer.exe 

Thanks for your help!